# Visual Studio 2012 Sql Anywhere Entityframework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, sqlanywhere

I am using Visual studio 2012 and SQL Anywhere 16, Create one MVC project and try  to create Entityframework edmx but when i select ODBC Database and test connection it shows me error that

> "Method not found: 'IntPtr'
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(!!0)'.
>   ".

Comment: Is there a reason you tagged it Sybase ASE?

Comment: Yes my database is created in sybase ASE. Its a Test.db which i restore in Sql anywhere and try to make EDMX by odbc.